# Change order of elements in grid view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change order of elements in grid by using jQuery.

I have something like this:

```
<div class="products products-grid  ">

<div class="box product">
  <figure>
    <div class="image-table">
      <div class="image-cell">
        <a href="xxx" class="product-image" >
          <img src="xxx" alt="111">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <figcaption>
      <div class="product-title">
        <a href="xxx" class="title">111</a>
      </div>
      <span class="price">
        <span class="money">xxx</span>
      </span>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>


<div class="box product">
  <figure>
    <div class="image-table">
      <div class="image-cell">
        <a href="xxx" class="product-image" >
          <img src="xxx" alt="222">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <figcaption>
      <div class="product-title">
        <a href="xxx" class="title">222</a>

      </div>
      <span class="price">
        <span class="money">xxx</span>
      </span>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>

<div class="box product">
  <figure>
    <div class="image-table">
      <div class="image-cell">
        <a href="xxx" class="product-image" >
          <img src="xxx" alt="333">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <figcaption>
      <div class="product-title">
        <a href="xxx" class="title">333</a>

      </div>
      <span class="price">
        <span class="money">xxx</span>
      </span>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

I need to change order of elements in "products products-grid", by alt defined in img src ... .
Lets say that I have multiple "box product" with alt = 222 inside, and I want them to be the first elements in "products products-grid". How could I do that using jQuery.

Comment: why do you want to use the `alt` attribute? It's basically for screenreaders (or if the image can't be displayed) to show a text instead. Would be better to use the `data` attribute for this. When do you want to change it? What has to happen before it gets changed? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want a user to be able to do the reodering (i.e. drag-and-drop or a button action to re-order)?  Or are you asking how you would manipulate the DOM before render?  Also, post what you've tried.

Comment: To answer both questions. This is existing code which I'm not able to change. The only thing that idendify entities in the code is alt attribute. I need to manipulate list using jQuery. I'd like to be able to execute method on every element with given 'alt' to push it to the top of the 'products products-grid'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty easy with jQuery

```
// With one item. Just grab it and throw it at the top
$('.products').prepend($('img[alt="222"]').closest('.product'));
```

With multiple, use each function (probably)

```
$('img[alt="222"]').each(function(){
   $('.products').prepend($(this).closest('.product'));
});
```

This code is untested. Syntax might have error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jquery plugin it will be very useful to you doing your required task
http://tinysort.sjeiti.com